# Abstract title does not show up in quarto pdf document

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto

Consider the following `quarto` document:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.
abstract-title: My abstract
---

Something.
```

The PDF output does not contain the abstract title. How can we fix that?

Comment: It seems `abstract-title` is only a html option

Comment: Thanks, @Maël, for your comment. If so, is it impossible to create an abstract title? I would expect being possible to insert an abstract title, as there are some `quarto` templates with which that is possible, even for PDF output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to pass the option `abstract` to the documentclass `scrartcl` to show the abstract title.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
classoption: abstract
keep-tex: true
abstract: |
  This is the abstract
---

Something.
```

Now following the above, will show the abstract title, titled as **Abstract** by default. If you want a different abstract title, modify the `\abstractname` with `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{<custom-abstract-title>}`.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
classoption: abstract
abstract: |
  This is the abstract
include-in-header: 
  text:
    \renewcommand{\abstractname}{My abstract}
---

Something.
```

[image: abstract title]